# Integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is not finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

Let  $ \mathbb{Z}^{'}_{\mathbb{C}}$ be the integral closure of $ \mathbb{Z} $ in $ \mathbb{C} $, i.e. $ \mathbb{Z}^{'}_{\mathbb{C}}$ contains all complex roots of polynomials with integer coefficients and $1$ as the leading coefficient.

Prove that $ \mathbb{Z}^{'}_{\mathbb{C}} $ is not finitely generated as a $ \mathbb{Z} $-module.

My attempt: Suppose $ \mathbb{Z}^{'}_{\mathbb{C}}=\mathbb{Z}\alpha_{1}+...+\mathbb{Z}\alpha_{n} $ for some $ \{ \alpha_{i}\}_{i=\overline{1,n}} \subset \mathbb{Z}^{'}_{\mathbb{C}} $. 
Let's take $ \alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{Z}^{'}_{\mathbb{C}} $ with minimal polynomials of degrees $ m $ and $ n $ respectively. We can construct a monic polynomial with integral coefficients $ P(z)=\prod(z-(\alpha_{i}+\beta_{j})) $ where $ \alpha_{i},\beta_{j} $ are the conjugates of $\alpha $ , $\beta $ and therefore the minimal polynomial of $ \alpha + \beta $ has degree $ \leq mn $.

I was thinking that the degrees of the minimal polynomials of the elements of $ \mathbb{Z}\alpha_{1}+...+\mathbb{Z}\alpha_{n} $ could be somehow bounded by a certain constant, whereas $ \mathbb{Z}^{'}_{\mathbb{C}}$ contains elements whose degrees of the minimal polynomials are arbitrarily large. I think this works when we are asked to prove that the set of all algebraic numbers $ \overline{\mathbb{Q}} $ is not a finitely dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, but I don't know how to proceed in my case.

I would really appreciate any ideas, hints or solutions. Thank you very much!

Comment: It is possible to use MathJax in titles as well.

Comment: Show that any element $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}'_c$ satisfies a monic polynomial of degree at most $n$ by noting that the rank of $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ as an abelian group is precisely the degree of the minimal monic polynomial satisfied by $a$.